# Routing and the "this" keyword

Tags: routes, meteor

if my route file looks like this

```
'/posts/:_id': {
        to: 'somePage',
        and: function(id) { Session.set('someId', id); }  }
```

and I use it in my html file like `{{somePagePath this}}` I know that `somePagePath` equals to `/post/`. But what does `this` mean in this context?

Could I write it differently?

Is it an object that binds my routed arguments? so this, is a shorthand for `this._id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to read Meteor's [wiki on templates and helpers](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars#expressions-with-dots).

> The expression {{this}} evaluates to the current data context. Paths starting with this always refer to properties of the current data context and not to helpers.

If `somePagePath` returns the string '/post/' then the template passes `this` as an argument but extra arguments get ignored by javascript so {{somePagePath this}} and {{somePagePath}} are the same.